# Laravel 5.3 class/routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Hej! My question is the next. I started to use Laravel 5.3. How can I do this `class` in Laravel:

```
class Vehicle
{
    public $vehicletype;

    function invt($vehicletype){
        $this->vehicletype=$vehicletype;
    }
    function outvt(){
        return $this->vehicletype;
    }
}
```

I already have ajax `.post` ,the route:

```
Route::get('/ajax-vehicletype',function(){
    $vehicletypevalue=Input::get('vehicletype');
    Vehicle::invt($vehicletypevalue);
});
```

I get error:

```
Non-static method App\Vehicle::invt() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with Laravel, learn the differences between static and non-static method calls in OOP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: You are not defining whether the functions are public, private, protected or static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define controller and then define function inside that controller and pass that in your route argument.

```
class Vehicle extends Controller{
      public $vehicletype;

      function invt($vehicletype){
           $this->vehicletype=$vehicletype;
      }
     function outvt(){
      ...........
      }
}
```

In your route file you can define the route as

```
Route::get('/ajax-vehicletype/{vehicletype}','Vehicle@invt');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn basic PHP first.

The problem you are facing is because you are calling non-static method statically as it is said in the error. The quick fix would be to define `invt` method as static: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php